# How to request extra oauth scopes in Meteor Accounts

Tags: oauth, meteor, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am using accounts-google to authenticate users for a Google Drive app written in Meteor. I want to request the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive scope along with the user.email and user.profile scopes that are requested by default. I think have seen this done with 'requestPermissions' but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Adding this code fixed the problem:

```
if (Meteor.isClient){
    var scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']
    Accounts.ui.config({'requestPermissions':{'google':scopes}});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, saved me a lot of time. :)